# Using PiPiper to control Energenie's Pi-mote

Tags: raspbian, gpio, ruby

I've just acquired myself a [Pi-mote from Energenie](https://energenie4u.co.uk/index.php/catalogue/product/ENER002-2PI).
I'm trying to replicate the code from [their website](https://energenie4u.co.uk/res/software/ENER002-2PI.py) using Ruby and the pi_piper gem, but I've run in to problems.

For some reason, my turn_1_on function works just fine. But none of the others seem to work. I have tested that it still works correctly and as intended throughout with the python script.

Code as follows:

```
require 'pi_piper'
  include PiPiper
  # Select the GPIO pins used for the encoder D0-D3 data inputs
  @pin11 = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 17, :direction => :out)
  @pin13 = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 27, :direction => :out)
  @pin15 = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 22, :direction => :out)
  @pin16 = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 23, :direction => :out)

  # Select the signal to select ASK/FSK
  @pin18 = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 24, :direction => :out)

  # Select the signal used to enable/disable the modulator
  @pin22 = PiPiper::Pin.new(:pin => 25, :direction => :out)

  # Disable the modulator by setting CE pin lo
  @pin22.off

  # Set the modulator to ASK for On Off Keying
  # by setting MODSEL pin lo
  @pin18.off

  # Initialise D0-D3 inputs of the encoder to 0000
  @pin11.off
  @pin13.off
  @pin15.off
  @pin16.off

  # The On/Off code pairs correspond to the hand controller codes.
  # True = '1', False ='0'

  def turn_1_on
    @pin11.on
    puts "Pin11 now has value #{@pin11.value}"
    @pin13.on
    puts "Pin13 now has value #{@pin13.value}"
    @pin15.on
    puts "Pin15 now has value #{@pin15.value}"
    @pin16.on
    puts "Pin16 now has value #{@pin16.value}"
    sleep(0.1)
    @pin22.on
    sleep(0.25)
    @pin22.off
  end

  def turn_1_off
    @pin11.on
    puts "Pin11 now has value #{@pin11.value}"
    @pin13.on
    puts "Pin13 now has value #{@pin13.value}"
    @pin15.on
    puts "Pin15 now has value #{@pin15.value}"
    @pin16.off
    puts "Pin16 now has value #{@pin16.value}"
    sleep(0.1)
    @pin22.on
    sleep(0.25)
    @pin22.off
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just been playing with this myself.  I'm sure you've already sorted it but your pin ordering is wrong -

The encoder signals are -

- D0 - GPIO pin 17 / Energenie board pin 11
- D1 - GPIO pin 22 / Energenie board pin 15
- D2 - GPIO pin 23 / Energenie board pin 16
- D3 - GPIO pin 27 / Energenie board pin 13

Socket 1 off is then 1, 1, 1, 0 -

```
  def turn_1_off
    @pin11.on
    puts "Pin11 now has value #{@pin11.value}"
    @pin13.off # <---- PIN 13 is off!
    puts "Pin13 now has value #{@pin13.value}"
    @pin15.on
    puts "Pin15 now has value #{@pin15.value}"
    @pin16.on
    puts "Pin16 now has value #{@pin16.value}"
    sleep(0.1)
    @pin22.on
    sleep(0.25)
    @pin22.off
  end
```